# Obj-C - Define UIColor property in NSObject?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

I'm trying to define UIColor in an NSObject, but this doesn't seem do-able? Sorry for the basic question, but I can't seem to find why this wouldn't work? The property line throws me the error:

> Unknown type name UIColor

**MyObject.h**

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface MyDataObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) UIColor *userColor;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must import UIKit:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```